# Quality factors relevant for getting a replacement battery (MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012))

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

The battery in my computer (MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)) is due:

[image]

I'd like to buy a new one. I'm looking for something efficient, i.e. having a long battery time and with the most refill.

What kind of characterstics/quality factors do I need to look for while searching for a replacement?

Comment: Why do you think it's "due?"  What are you experiencing that makes you think that?

Comment: Hello @Allan! Sometimes I like to work in a coffee. However, often the electrical outlet are all used. I install myself at a free table, and my battery discharge quickly. It is good for at most an hour. That why I want to change my battery.

Comment: Your battery is definitely on the verge of needing to be replaced. You don't really have much of a choice in terms of batteries. I'd suggest going with a replicable company provider. OWC might be helpful getting you started in the right direction: https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/BAP13MBU65V/

Comment: @Allan I think SpinningAtInfinity is right that it's due for replacement because it's 4.5 years old and the battery status is at warning level. I recently had a similarly old MBA battery die on me. I replaced it with an OWC battery with good results

Comment: What was the lifetime of your new battery at the time

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B00UPV12D8?psc=1 : Is it a good battery for my MBP?

Comment: I was busy editing my answer with pictures and I just now saw your comment....  I would definitely recommend the Lizone.  I've used them before (actually still using one in my 2010 MBP) - going on about the 2nd year with zero issues.

Comment: I just want to be sure of my purchase. Does this model amazon.ca/dp/B00UPV12D8?psc=1 is compatible with my MBP?

Comment: Based on everything you have in your question - basically a Mid 2012 MBP A1278 MacbookPro9,2 - yes;  that battery will fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different battery manufacturers out there; the problem with figuring out which one is the better of all the others is you never know which one will perform and which one won't.

Pretty much all will have the correct specs and will connect to your device whether that be a MacBook Pro, an alarm system or a back up UPS.  What I have found in my many years of experience is to **go with the vendor that offers the best warranty.**

Generally speaking when I went "cheap" I ended up having to replace the battery much sooner than expected.  If I spent a little more on a battery with an 18 month or 24 month warranty, I usually got 3-5 years out of it which is the norm for me.

[Egoway](http://radnex.us/Ergoway_MBP_13-inch_battery_A1278_A1322) and [Lizone](http://radnex.us/Lizone_MBP_13-inch_battery_2009-2012) are two batteries that I would recommend as replacements for your particular MacBook Pro.

Replacing them is pretty simple too.  You basically remove the 10 scews on the back and remove the back cover to expose the logic board and battery.  Remove the battery connector from the logic board (on the right) and pull the battery up by the tab.  Just reverse the steps to install the new one.

The pictures below give an abridged version of this procedure, but you can find the full detailed instructions on [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Battery+Replacement/10365)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: iFixit also sell their own line of batteries, links from each DIY page, and OWC have their NewerTech brand [higher output [75W/h] than either the original Apple battery 55W/h or the iFixit [65W/h] but more expensive. Links current at Dec 2023 - https://www.ifixit.com/products/macbook-pro-13-unibody-mid-2009-mid-2012-replacement-battery and https://www.newertech.com/batteries/