# Why is my Early 2014 MacBook Air's Trackpad Uneven?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, trackpad

My Early 2014 MacBook Air's trackpad is uneven; it's hard to click on the top left corner of the trackpad but it's easy to click on the bottom right corner.

Is this supposed to happen, or is there a problem, say, something is stuck under the top left corner of the trackpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the [battery being swollen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/359218/119271).

When you get a physical "deformity" like this, it's due to one of two things:

- accidental (or intentional) damage where the case and components don't line up anymore
- something putting physical strain on the components themselves.

I'm assuming you didn't drop the Mac or have something heavy impact it.

The battery swells because of off gasses being trapped and it's something you need to fix right away as the trapped gasses at a minimum can damage your Mac (what you're experiencing) to becoming a fire hazard due to [thermal runaway](http://thesciencedictionary.org/thermal-runaway/).

If you have the technical skills, you can remove the battery and continue to operate your Mac without it as you wait for [a replacement battery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259469/119271) to arrive.

The battery is located just below the logic board - the four black "squares".  It's an entire module that can be replaced by removing the five screws (red/orange circles denoting different sizes.)  For full removal instructions, see [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2014+Battery+Replacement/24738)

[image: 2014 MacBook Air 13" Battery]
<sup>Image Source:  Ifixit.com</sup>